# Latex code for the Routh-Hurwitz criterion?

Tags: matrices

Can anybody please help me in writing the Latex code that creates this? Thanks!
[image]

Comment: welcome to tex.se! what you try so far? it will help you if you will read some introductory text how to write math in latex, for example  https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really do not need anything special for that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[ H_n=\det\begin{bmatrix}
 a_1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
 a_3 & a_2 & a_1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
 a_5 & a_4 & a_3 & a_2 & a_1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & a_n
\end{bmatrix}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]